# Powershell html string get value

Tags: powershell

I have a decoded html tag value is a string variable like this

```
$Body = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($field.GetAttribute("Value"))
```

Output of the Body is like this

```
"<div class="1A00360973">6930-20-000</div>"
```

the class value is dynamic. How can i get the div value using powershell ?

Comment: Are the enclosing double quotes really part of the output?